# Norm $-1$ elements of quaternion algebras and Shimura curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $Qa$ be an indefinite quaternion algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Let $O$ be an order of $Qa$. The moduli space of abelian surfaces with quaternionic multiplication by $O$ is usually designed as the Shimura curve $H/O^1$ where $O^1$ is the sub-group of elements of norm $1$ of $O^*$, and $H$ is the upper half-plane.
I am troubled by the fact that this seems to not take care of the full group $O^*$:

> **Question.** Why elements of norm $-1$ are not taken into account ?

I understand that if $H^-$ denotes the lower half plane, an element of norm $-1$ exchanges the two half-planes $H$ and $H^-$, so the quotient of $H\cup H^-$  by $O^*$ should be the same as the quotient of $H$ by $O^1$.
It seems that in most of the studied cases there is always an element of norm $-1$ in $O$, however:

When $O$ does not contain elements of norm $-1$, the action of $O^*=O^1$ on $H \cup H^-$ also exists, and the quotient is the union of two Shimura curves.
Let $\Phi : H \to M_2(\mathbb R)$ be an embedding (as classically defined by exemple in the book of Bayer, Montserrat) and let $$A_z=\mathbb{C}^2/\Phi(O).(z,1)^t,$$  the QM-abelian surface associated to $z$ in $H \cup H^-$.
It could be possible that the abelian surfaces $A_z, A_{z’}$ are never isomorphic if $z$ is in $H$ and $z’$ is in $H^-$, which would give that the moduli space of abelian surfaces with QM by $O$ has two irreducible components.
Is that known ? Is there a general argument if this is the case or not ?

Comment: That question has been associated to the question  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95727/existence-of-elements-in-an-eichler-order-whose-norm-is-minus-one?noredirect=1&lq=1 but it seems that does not solve my problem, and a reformulation of the question is in the following post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392135/shimura-curves-and-quaternion-orders-without-elements-of-norm-1