# Shimura curves and quaternion orders without elements of norm -1

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $O$ be an order of a quaternion algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $O$ does not contain elements of norm $-1$. Such orders exist, but seems less used, in particular these orders are not Eichler.

Let $\Phi : H \to M_2(\mathbb R)$ be an embedding (as classically defined by exemple in the book of Bayer, Montserrat) and let $$A_z=\mathbb{C}^2/\Phi(O).(z,1)^t,$$  the QM-abelian surface associated to $z$ in the upper-plane.
Note that one also can take $z$ in the lower half plane $H^-$, and get also an abelian surface, which we denote also $A_z$.

The moduli space of Abelian surfaces with QM by $O$ is defined as the Shimura curve $C=H/O^1$, where $O^1$, the group of invertible elements acts by homographic transformations. In our situation, since there are no norm $-1$ elements, one has $O^*=O^1$.

Since $C$ is a moduli space, any surface $A_z$ with $z\in H^-$ should be isomorphic to a surface $A_{\varphi(z)}$ for some $\varphi(z)\in H$.

> **Question.** What is the transformation $\varphi$ that maps an abelian surface $A_{z}$ with $z \in H^-$ to a surface in the moduli $C$ ?

My worries is that if there is no such $\varphi$, one miss an irreducible component of the moduli space of the abelian surfaces with QM by $O$.

This question is a complete reformulation of the question:
[Norm $-1$ elements of quaternion algebras and Shimura curves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392078/norm-1-elements-of-quaternion-algebras-and-shimura-curves)
which has been associated with a similar question
[Existence of elements in an Eichler order whose norm is minus one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95727/existence-of-elements-in-an-eichler-order-whose-norm-is-minus-one)
. But this similar question (with also that trouble to understand if there is not a missing irreducible component of the moduli) is for Eichler orders. The answer is that for Eichler order there is always an element of norm $-1$, (so that another irreducible component does not exist)  and this doesn’t resolve my question...

Comment: "The moduli space of Abelian surfaces .. is defined as $H/O^1$" -- this is nonsense. The moduli space of ab surfaces with O-multiplication is a uniquely defined object, and it either is, or isn't, isomorphic to $H / O^1$; you can't make two different things become isomorphic by defining them to be so. In fact, it looks to me as if you've given a convincing argument why that moduli space *cannot* be isomorphic to $H / O^1$ if $O$ doesn't have an element of norm $-1$.

Comment: As explained in the other question which I linked your last question to, the moduli space is actually $B^\times \backslash (\widehat{B}^\times \times H) / \widehat{O}^\times$, where B is your quat alg and $\widehat{B} = B \otimes \mathbf{A}_f$, $\widehat{O} = O \otimes \widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$. By strong approximation, this has the same connected components as $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}^\times / Nm(\widehat{O}^\times)$.

Comment: Well, @DavidLoeffler about the sentence you do not like, I agree this is a bad formulation, I should have written that in the litterature, one finds often that the moduli of abelian surfaces with QM by $O$ is isomorphic to $H/O^1$. About the math contents of your answer, for which I thank you, could you give more explanations for someone that do not knows about these objects ? By example, concretely, what does that means in the situation I am asking ? Thanks